# In Drupal every radio button with in a label enclosed with span or div tag

Tags: drupal

In drupal in i am creating 4 radio buttons in a group.
I want to have a div tag or span tag for every radio button 
by using prefix and suffix drupal is placing div or span tag 
before or after entire radio butons group, but i need a div or span tag before every radio button.
I searched in the web for many hours but no luck.
If there is a solution pls post it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: Here is my code                                                'code'                                                 $form['choice'] = array(
   '#type' => 'radios',
   '#options' => $options,    
  ); 'code'

Answer (score 0):

i dont think you can add wrappers per radio button with #prefix and #suffix. [form_process_radios](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_process_radios/7)

Expands a radios element into individual radio element. each radio is rendered with [theme_radio](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_radio/7).

You can wrap each individual radio button by overriding the theme_radio function.

Hope that helps.